# how android application to sdcard service

Tags: android, io, ipc, android-sdcard

I noticed there's a program named sdcard, which includes two threads in android system. When I tried to read/write sdcard in my application, all I/O requests are submitted from these two threads. So I checked the AOSP, and found the code in [AOSP]/system/core/sdcard/sdcard.c. Here's some explanation about this:

*sdcard is a program that uses FUSE to emulate FAT-on-sdcard style directory permissions (all files are given fixed owner, group, and permissions at creation, owner, group, and permissions are not changeable, symlinks and hardlinks are not createable, etc.*

So, my question is, how my application submits these I/O calls to sdcard threads in details? I checked the code but didn't find some binder stuff.

Answer (score 2):

It says it uses FUSE.  FUSE is a part of linux that allows regular file commands (read, write, open, delete, etc) to a given folder to be sent to an application instead.  For example, you could map the folder http to a FUSE filesystem that sends HTTP requests, and try to access remote files as if they were local ones.

In this case, they mapped the sd card to this program via FUSE, so all the reads/writes come from a single application.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. What I'm trying to do is adding a parameter passing from the original application who launches the I/O requests to sdcard threads. Do you know how I can do that? Because usually android uses binder to do IPC stuff, but in that sdcard file I didn't find related codes.

Comment: Maybe a custom ioctl?  You'd need a custom kernel to do it though.  This literally uses the Linux filesystem calls to pass parameters, its not really possible to add parameters.

Comment: Sorry can you explain the "filesystem calls" or give some references? I've never knew this before. I still don't get it when my application calls a java API to read a file from sdcard and how many stages or steps it go through to go to this sdcard service... Thanks so much.

Comment: kernel level filesystem calls.  open(), write(), read(), close(), ioctl(), etc.  The actual Linux kernel functions that the absolute lowest level libraries on the device like libc use when they want to write to the filesystem.  http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lki/lki-3.html